# Go-to way for sidebar + two column lay-out with different heights?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am working on a website with the following lay-out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGXhO.png

Info;

- Red marked is a (fixed) side-bar which should collapse / fold on a
  mobile.
- The other blocks are just divs with variable heights.

Now I was / am wondering what the best approach would be to create this. I tried several, starting from putting the content (variable height divs) both in a wrapper which was given a float: left to (trying to) use jQuery Masonry. Both ways being unsuccesfull so far. For some reason my divs won't flow next to each other.

These are the heights of the divs I use, based on my design;

```
#green {
    height: 312px;
}

#blue {
    height: 752px;
}

#orange {
    height: 876px;
}

#purple {
    height: 618px;
}

#yellow {
    height: 876px;
}
```

Could someone send me into the right direction?

Edit; what I forgot to mention is that when I make the screen smaller, the content blocks should be put below each other. (And the side-bar should collapse but I will look into that 'problem' later.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating 2 parent elements. Something like `.sidebar` and `.content`. You can then float these those using `float: left` on each.

You HTML would look similar to:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="red"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div id="purple"></div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS would look like:

```
.sidebar,
.content {
  float: right;
}
```

A different solution could be to use flexbox. To do this, you should create another parent element around the sidebar and content. The CSS for this would look like (No longer needing the previous CSS):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar,
.content {
  width: 33%; // Or however wide you need these 
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Mhm. The sidebar on the left is actually my menu bar which is rather fixed. (Only on responsive it should collapse but that's not my current problem, haha.) - So I tried to do your solution here;

https://jsfiddle.net/ejncny9z/4/

But as you can see everything is below each other instead of next of each other. What am I doing wrong here? (Of-course I could give the parent a margin-left of 250px but then still the content is below each other.)

Comment: I've updated the fiddle for you, hope this helps!
https://jsfiddle.net/ejncny9z/8/

As I understand you want the menu fixed above it? You could create another div outside the parent, and have it fixed above the current one,  using it as a placeholder.